# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable while running in online IDE

Tags: python, list, typeerror

> The below code outputs a spiral matrix of size(n*n)

```
def generateMatrix(self, a):
        #generates a list with specified elemnts from 1 to n^2
        x = [list(range(i, i+a)) for i in range(1, a**2, a)]

        numrows = len(x)
        numcols = len(x[0])
        top = 0
        bottom = numrows-1
        left = 0
        right = numcols-1
        direction = 0
        b = []

        while (top <= bottom and left <= right):
            if direction is 0:
                for i in range(left, right+1):
                    b.append(x[top][i])
                top += 1
            elif direction is 1:
                for i in range(top, bottom+1):
                    b.append(x[i][right])
                right -= 1
            elif direction is 2:
                for i in range(right, left-1, -1):
                    b.append(x[bottom][i])
                bottom -= 1
            elif direction is 3:
                for i in range(bottom, top-1, -1):
                    b.append(x[i][left])
                left += 1
            direction = (direction+1) % 4
        return b
```

> While running this code in online IDE I am getting 
>   TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable.
>   I have checked if I am iterating wrongly in the code. But could not find any problems as such. I know this question has been asked before and I have checked the solutions. But nothing is working. Can anyone inspect what is wrong with my code?

Comment: I cannot see any issues running on Jupyter. Can you point the line on which you are seeing this error.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Do you have a full traceback of the exception? It should tell you exactly where the error is occurring.

Comment: I am getting no issues with this code at all. Have you tried another IDE? It could just be the IDE its self with an issue.

Comment: Here is the code running fine: https://repl.it/repls/PointlessSqueakyComputation

Did you define your own function called range? Don't do that.

Comment: Actually I am practicing Arrays in InterviewBit. So, I ave used InterviewBit IDE itself.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 227, in 
    print_list_list(Z, False)
  `File "main.py", line 204, in print_list_list
    for i in newL:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`